# Is there an lldb equivalent to gdbserver?

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb, osx-mavericks, lldb

I have recently started developing on macOS and need to remotely debug a process by kicking off a debug server and connecting to it from another machine. Using GDB I would do this on the machine to be debugged:

`gdbserver :<port> --attach <pid>`

However, GDB appears to no longer be supported on macOS as the community has apparently transitioned to using `lldb`. However, I am unable to find the equivalent command for kicking off a debug server using lldb. I found [this](http://lldb.llvm.org/lldb-gdb.html) equivalency page, but the only mention of something similar is using lldb as a *client* that connects to some remote server.

I have found mention of a `lldb-server` command, but I am unable to find documentation on how to install it as it did not come with the standard command-line tools package on macOS.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I forgot to add OSX tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On macOS systems, use `debugserver`.  e.g. at `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/LLDB.framework/Resources/debugserver`

On linux, use `lldb-server`.

`debugserver` was written before lldb was, and is a bit of a developmental dead-end; at some point in the future `lldb-server` will be updated to handle all the macOS specific features and `debugserver` will be retired.  There's no concrete plans to do that work in the immediate future though.

Comment: I saw mention of this on another question but was not able to get it working initially. Apparently the argument format of `debugserver host:port --attach=<pid>` refers to the `host` IP address of the remote server from which you are expecting a connection. Otherwise you will see something like `error: rejecting incoming connection from <ip> (expecting <ip from arg>)`.